# Show that all terms of a sequence are whole numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ for which $a_1=1,a_2=143$ and $a_{n+1}=5\cdot\dfrac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$ for every $n\ge2$. Show that all terms of the sequence are whole numbers.

I don't know how to approach the problem. Am I supposed to use induction?

For example, the third term of the sequence is $$a_3=5\cdot\dfrac{a_1+a_2}{2}=5\dfrac{144}{2}=5\cdot72=360$$

Comment: I'd suggest trying values other than $143$, which seems kind of random. For which values does the sequence appear to stay integral?

Comment: Suppose that :$$ n | a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n$$ and prove that : $$n | a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n+a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

This has (slightly) the look of a homework problem so I will not give a *solution* but here are a couple of hints that may be more broadly applicable.

1. It shouldn't be too painful to compute a few more terms of the sequence explicitly. You should always do this and look to see whether you can just spot what the sequence seems to be (in which case maybe there'll be a proof by induction or something), or spot some relationship between the elements of the sequence that's simpler than the one you have already (in which case, maybe you can prove that simpler relationship and then use that to prove the result you actually want).
2. The thing that makes this awkward is the $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. Can you find a way to get rid of it, yielding a recurrence relation that's easier to work with? (Hint 1: Yes. Hint 2: If you subtract one of those from another, most of the terms will cancel out.)